# Overwrite printed line in python 3.x on mac

Tags: python, macos, carriage-return, sys

I'm attempting to write a program that involves the use of a coin flip, heads or tails, but so that it will print 'heads' then be replaced by 'tails' and continue doing this until it decides on an answer.

At the moment, when I run the program, it prints the 'heads' or 'tails' on the next line every time. This happens on both Idle and Terminal.

I've tried using carriage return (\r), backspace (\b) and sys.stdout.write() and .flush() but neither are working, it just keeps printing on the next line.

Is there either another way of erasing what's been printed or is there other software I can use?
Here is my code:

```
import time
import random

offset = random.randint(0,1)

for i in range (0, 20+offset):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("Heads")
    else:
        print("Tails")
    print("\r")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` writes a `\n` character to the end, therefore you need to modify that if you want to keep on the same line.

```
import time
import random

offset = random.randint(0,1)

for i in range (0, 20+offset):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("Heads", end='')
    else:
        print("Tails", end='')
    print("\r", end='')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Edit: That only works for python 3, If you want to use that in python 2 then you need to write to sys.stdout

```
import time
import random
import sys  

offset = random.randint(0,1)

for i in xrange(0, 20+offset):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        sys.stdout.write("Heads")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Tails")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.flush()  
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
```

I'm aware this might not be the fastest implemention, but It works, I could type a faster approach later

Comment: This is the most specific answer. Removing mine.

Comment: I'm still getting a space between lines, there's no change when I do this on idle and terminal is now saying that there is an invalid syntax on line 8 - print("Heads", end='')

Comment: This code will never work on IDLE, due to some weird '\r' mechanism implemented in IDLE, try using it from a terminal, or the python exe

Comment: Terminal is working now with the second program, even though I'm in python 3 and not 2, thank you :D