# How to refresh the Console in the same line in real time, Python

Tags: python, macos, console

I'm trying to do the text refresh to be able to display some information in the same line, basically rewriting the old text.

code sample:

```
from time import sleep

def countdown(n):
    if n > 0 :
        print(n)
        sleep(0.3)
        countdown(n-1)
    else :
        print("Blastoff!")
countdown(3)
```

If I use the "\r" in the print statement, it does \n two times.

I tried the carriage return "\r" and the cls clear() function, everything on stack, but nothing works for Mac.

## code sample:

```
from time import sleep

def countdown(n):
    if n > 0 :
        print(n)
        sleep(0.3)
        countdown(n-1)
    else :
        print("Blastoff!")
countdown(6)
```

If I use the "\r" in the print statement, it does \n two times.
this is the current output:
3
2
1
Blastoff!

## in the same window.

i'd like to have the output as follows:
3     # in the first line

2     # in the same spot that 3 was.. and so on.
.
.
Blastoff!   # at the end will be the only thing on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

The print statement appends a new line at the end of your output by default.
To prevent this you want to add `end=""` as parameter. Now your output will always be on the same line.
In addition to this you want to use `"\r"` at the beginning of you output.

If you would add `"\r"` at the end of the output some consoles might overwrite your output while doing the carriage return and you would end up with a blank line.

I'd also avoid using recursion here, iteration is usually the faster way and unless it over complicates your code I - personally - would prefer it.

```
def countdown(n):
    while 0 < n:
        # add some spaces after the number to make sure we overwrite the entire last output
        print("\r%d   " % n, end="")
        n -= 1
        sleep(0.3)
    print("\rBlastoff!")
```

## Edit

Taken from here: [Overwrite printed line in python 3.x on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514938/overwrite-printed-line-in-python-3-x-on-mac)

Replace `print(...)` with `sys.stdout.write(...)` aswell as

```
def countdown(n):
    while 0 < n:
        sys.stdout.write("\r%d   " % n)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        n -= 1
        sleep(0.3)
    sys.stdout.write("\rBlastoff!")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

You will also need to `import sys`

Comment: it does not work. it outputs
2
1
0
Blastoff!
with two spaces between the lines. i want that all in one line and rewritten.

Comment: Are you using python 2?

Comment: i am using 3.7.1

Comment: Hmm... that's strange, the snippet I gave in my answer should work just fine. You could try adding `import os` to your imports and `os.system('cls')` after `sleep(0.3)`. This would clear the console after you printed something.

Comment: the same output, maybe it has to do something that i am running python on mac? i'm getting kinda desperate here. nothing works.

Comment: I do not use mac myself but it does seem to make a difference (according to google). I updated my answer, go try it again ;)

Comment: Kanjiu i tried it that way, and with multiple variations from the question you mentioned. it now prints in one line but liek this : 321Blastoff! , nothing gets refreshed but i guess we made a progress :D

Comment: Well - some progress, sigh - So after knowing you are using mac os I did some more reading and it seems the console command to clear the console on mac os is`clear` not `cls` as on windows. You could try verifying this by simply opening a console and typing `clear` to see if it clears the console. If it does you can use the approach I pointed out in my second comment but use `os.system('clear')`. If not we'll have to keep digging...

Comment: i found out that clearing the screen from IDLE in python is impossible without external modules. There is no workaround that. Thanks for your time @Kanjiu , glad there was someone willing to help :) have a nice day